# Hive sort array column with respect to other array column in same table

Tags: sql, arrays, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a table in hive , with 2 columns as `col1 array<int>` and `col2 array<double>`. Output is as shown below

```
col1                col2
[1,2,3,4,5]         [0.43,0.01,0.45,0.22,0.001]
```

I want to sort this col2 in ascending order and col1 should also change its index accordingly for e.g.

```
col1                col2
[5,2,4,3,1]        [0.001,0.01,0.22,0.43,0.45]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explode both arrays, sort, then aggregate arrays again. Use `sort` in the subquery before `collect_list` to sort the array:

```
with your_data as(
select array(1,2,3,4,5) as col1,array(0.43,0.01,0.45,0.22,0.001)as col2
)

select original_col1,original_col2, collect_list(c1_x) as new_col1, collect_list(c2_x) as new_col2
from
(
select d.col1 as original_col1,d.col2 as original_col2, c1.x as c1_x, c2.x as c2_x, c1.i as c1_i  
 from your_data d
      lateral view posexplode(col1) c1 as i,x
      lateral view posexplode(col2) c2 as i,x
where c1.i=c2.i 
distribute by original_col1,original_col2
sort by c2_x
)s
group by original_col1,original_col2;
```

Result:

```
OK
original_col1   original_col2                   new_col1        new_col2
[1,2,3,4,5]     [0.43,0.01,0.45,0.22,0.001]     [5,2,4,1,3]     [0.001,0.01,0.22,0.43,0.45]
Time taken: 34.642 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Edit: Simplified version of the same script, you can do without second posexplode, use direct reference by position `d.col2[c1.i] as c2_x`

```
with your_data as(
select array(1,2,3,4,5) as col1,array(0.43,0.01,0.45,0.22,0.001)as col2
)

select original_col1,original_col2, collect_list(c1_x) as new_col1, collect_list(c2_x) as new_col2
from
(
select d.col1 as original_col1,d.col2 as original_col2, c1.x as c1_x, d.col2[c1.i] as c2_x, c1.i as c1_i  
 from your_data d
      lateral view posexplode(col1) c1 as i,x
distribute by original_col1,original_col2
sort by c2_x
)s
group by original_col1,original_col2;
```

Comment: Working as expected, Thank you much @leftjoin, can you please help me on this question too if possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57310000/hive-sort-operation-on-high-volume-skewed-dataset

Comment: @nilesh1212.  I would if I could, but I can't so I won't. Upvoted, interesting, maybe someone else will help