# In Hive, how to convert an array of string to an array of numeric numbers

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, hiveql, numeric

I have a hive table that looks like the following:

```
id | value
 1 | ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0']
 2 | ['2', '0', '3', '0', '3', '1', '2', '1']
```

I want the result to be the following:

```
id | value
 1 | [0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0]
 2 | [2,0,3,0,3,1,2,1]
```

I need to convert them into an array of float so that I can use them in `ST_Constains(ST_MultiPolygon(), st_point())` to determine if a point is in an area.

I am new to Hive, not sure if that is possible, any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explode array, cast value, collect array again. 
Demo:

```
with your_table as(
select stack(2,
 1 , array('0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0'),
 2 , array('2', '0', '3', '0', '3', '1', '2', '1')
 ) as (id,value)
 ) --use your_table instead of this


 select s.id, 
        s.value                            as original_array, 
        collect_list(cast(s.str as float)) as array_float 
 from
(select t.*, s.* 
 from your_table t
               lateral view outer posexplode(t.value)s as pos,str       
   distribute by t.id, t.value 
         sort by s.pos --preserve order in the array
 )s  
group by s.id, s.value;
```

Result:

```
OK
1       ["0","0","1","0","1","1","0","0"]       [0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0]
2       ["2","0","3","0","3","1","2","1"]       [2.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,3.0,1.0,2.0,1.0]
```

See also this answer about sorting array in the query https://stackoverflow.com/a/57392965/2700344

Comment: Thanks very much. This is what exactly what I want. I takes me a long time to understand every steps in your code. None of the line is useless. I am appreciated.

Comment: @GuanyanLin You are welcome! If it helps, please accept/vote